# Виртуальный сервер на FreeBSD

Tags: веб-сервер, freebsd

Расскажите о всех шагах, которые необходимо выполнить для того, чтобы поднять FreeBSD вместе со стеком FAMP (виртуальный веб сервер для 10 сайта ) и несколькими инструментами администрирования на абсолютно голом сервере и сделать так, чтобы все это работало вместе без сбоев и непредвиденных ситуаций.

Answer (score 1):

- [Установка веб-сервера на FreeBSD](http://anton-pribora.ru/articles/os/freebsd/freebsd-apache-mysql-php/)
- [Установка FAMP (FreeBSD+Apache+MySQL+PHP)](http://adminotes.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-famp-freebsdapachemysqlphp/)

Answer (score 0):

В 5 минут вам никто не раскажет и не поможет. Но есть замечательная статья на [хакере](http://www.xakep.ru/post/57595/default.asp)

Comment: Без сбоев - это если вы четко знаете, что делаете. Мне пришлось раза три начинать с нуля прежде чем запустить сервер в продакшен. На текущий момент уже 8 месяцев работает с кучей сервисов "без сбоев и непредвиденных ситуаций"